# How to update when view within scrollview is displayed? Viewdidload not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nsuserdefaults

Im in a bit of a sticky situation because my app is designed like Snapchat in that I have 3 views (3 different xibs and classes) that are all contained in a scrollview. Here is my set up in ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let v1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
        let v2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)
        let v3 : View3 = View3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(v1)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v1.view)
        v1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.addChildViewController(v2)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v2.view)
        v2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.addChildViewController(v3)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v3.view)
        v3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        var v2Frame : CGRect = v2.view.frame
        v2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        v2.view.frame = v2Frame

        var v3Frame : CGRect = v3.view.frame
        v3Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * 2
        v3.view.frame = v3Frame

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, self.view.frame.height)


    }
```

ViewdidLoad is only called once by my view controller and these subviews when the app is FIRST OPENED, meaning it is not called again and again by my subviews when I scroll through. My problem with this is I have no way to UPDATE labels in my subviews as I have no "update" function-

I store several ints/values in NSUserdefaults and these change as the app is run. In `View1`I have 3 labels that display int values pertaining to certain keys:

```
if prefs.objectForKey("photos") != nil //fix for cross updating
        {
            photos.text = String(self.prefs.integerForKey("photos"))
        }
        else {
            photos.text = "0"
        }
```

This works great but only when the app is first opened. If `prefs.integerForKey("photos")`changes as the app is run, when I flip back to `View1`the label still displays the same old value. I have no way of calling the above code block again to update the label.

I have tried `prefs.synchronize()` hoping this might affect something, but no success. This is a large problem.

Should I try to make the labels public and change them directly from the other view? Is there an update function similar to the one in sprite kit that I can call before each frame?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You should have functions in your child view controllers that update label's text. Something like `updatePhotoLabelWithInt(int: Int)`.

2: Another option is have computed properties set up for your child view controllers, or stored properties and observed those properties like so:

```
// Option 1
var numberOfPhotos: Int {
    get { Int(label.text)! }
    set { label.text = String(newValue) }
}

// Option 2
var numberOfPhotos: Int {
    didSet { label.text = String(numberOfPhotos) }
}
```

`NSUserDefaults` is used when you want to store certain values, even when the app is terminated. Unless you want to keep those values, use properties, variables instead.

Also, you don't seem to name your variables/properties very descriptively. Using the name `photos` for a label is a bad idea. Should be something like `photoLabel`.